# loop over a list of tables and field and mix them

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, loops, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking for an effective method to cover a given list of tables and fields that need to be mixed.

I suppose this should become a function or stored procedure.

The input should be some sort of list of table names, and for each table there should be another list with it's Unique index column, a key column and then all the other columns that need to be mixed.

The algorithm and the given code are explained below:

Fist of all, by mixing I mean keeping all values in each column but redestribute them between the rows in a different order.

The SQL syntax :

```
declare @tablename varchar, @keyColumn varchar, @ColumnForBase  ,@ColumnToMix 

update [@tablename] 
set [@tablename].[@ColumnToMix]=c.[@ColumnToMix],[@tablename].[@ColumnForBase]=c.[@ColumnForBase]
from [@tablename] left join
(
    SELECT a.[@ColumnToMix] as [@ColumnToMix] ,b.[@ColumnForBase] as [@ColumnForBase],b.[@keyColumn] as [@keyColumn]
    FROM
        (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [@ColumnToMix]) num, [@ColumnToMix]
        FROM [@tablename]) as a 
        left join
        (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [@ColumnForBase]) num, [@keyColumn],[@ColumnForBase]
        FROM [@tablename] ) as b 
        ON a.num=b.num
)as c  ON c.[@keyColumn]=[@tablename].[@keyColumn]
```

Explanation and example:

Say I have a table with 4 columns: Index, Id, Name, Address
The algorithm reorders the Ids and the Names, adding a number to each line.
Since there are the same number of lines I can join the two reordered columns by line numbers and then update the original table - changing one column (ColumnToMix) to the redistributed values.
Say the original table is called "People" and looks like this:

```
Index Id   Name   Address 
1     52   Jill   New-York
2     57   John   Chicago
5     63   Bill   Alabama
```

The variables would be
 @tablename = people, @keyColumn = Index, @ColumnForBase = Id  ,@ColumnToMix = Name

The result of running the code above would be

```
Index Id   Name   Address 
1     52   Bill   New-York
2     57   Jill   Chicago
5     63   John   Alabama
```

The names are now mixed.

In order to mix more then one column the code needs to be able to loop over all necessary fields.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This seems like a dangerous idea.... A row is a unit of data, mixing up a specific column (or columns) in the database like you describe means messing up the data to a point it will no longer make sense and potentially no turning back (except restore an older backup). Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: The idea is to intentionally mix the data in order to get a randomly different dataset. It's good for QA and can be also used to scramble data taken from real environments to test environments.

Comment: ...and can also be used (either by mistake or maliciously) to change a production database to a point it's unusable, or perhaps even to hack it (mixing up usernames or passwords in the users table, for instance). BTW, you would have a better chance of getting an answer if you specify what rdbms you are working with (brand and version)

Comment: thx,added rdbms specification.
About the usage - any DELETE or DROP TABLE  can be equally or more dangerous, obviously this should be used with caution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one hard coded column it's a fairly simple task:

```
UPDATE T0
SET Name = T1.Name
FROM 
(
    SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OriginalOrderColumn) As RN
    FROM Table
) AS T0
JOIN
(
    SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) As RN
    FROM Table
) AS T1
ON T0.RN = T1.RN
```

*OriginalOrderColumn means a column that represents the "natural" order - like an identity column or a create date column. Please note that records in a table have no natural order since tables are unsorted by definition.

But in order to parameterize the table name and column names, you would need to use dynamic SQL in a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MixValuesInAColumn
(
    @TableName sysname, 
    @ColumnToMix sysname, 
    @OriginalOrderBy sysname
)
AS
-- White-listing table and column names
IF EXISTS
(
     SELECT 1 
     FROM Information_Schema.Columns
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
     AND COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnToMix 
 ) AND EXISTS
(
     SELECT 1 
     FROM Information_Schema.Columns
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
     AND COLUMN_NAME = @OriginalOrderBy 
 ) BEGIN

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = 
    'UPDATE T0 SET '+ QUOTENAME(@ColumnToMix) +' = T1.'+ QUOTENAME(@ColumnToMix) +' '+ 
    'FROM (
        SELECT '+ @ColumnToMix +', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY '+ QUOTENAME(@OriginalOrderBy) +') As [Original Order] 
        FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '
    ) As T0
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT '+ QUOTENAME(@ColumnToMix) +', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) As [Random Order] 
        FROM '+ QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '
    ) AS T1 ON T0.[Original Order] = T1.[Random Order]'

EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

I would recommend not mixing multiple columns in one execute, since they will all be mixed in the same random order - however you can create another procedure to take the parameters you wanted (a table name, it's primary key and a list of it's columns to mix) and run this procedure for each column separately.

[You can see a live demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/RWY14520) (based on the sample data you've provided).

Comment: Youll want to validate or quote the objects here. `@ColumnToMix` could easily be used to inject here.

Comment: @Larnu You are correct, and I've thought about mentioning that - but then again, if this procedure would be executed by a malicious person, it can cause real damage to the database even without using SQL injection. BTW, actually that's correct for all parameters of this procedure.

Comment: @Larnu I've added a white-list test.

Comment: That certainly makes thing a lot safer. I'd add `QUOTENAME` anyway, but that's more in case the OP has any objects with characters like a white space, right bracket, starts with a numeric, etc. God forbid the OP has an object called `sys.objects]; DROP TABLE MyTable;--`, but a malicious person might well try it if they can somehow create it first. Also, changing from a `nvarchar(4000)` to `sysname` was the right choice here. :)

Comment: @Larnu It was `nvarchar(4000)` when I first started toying with the idea and thought about changing more than one column in a single update statement... changing it to sysname was something I should have done before posting the first version of this answer. Good point about illegal chars in column names - I always forget that's a possibility (perhaps because I never thought using "strange" names is a good option)

Comment: Thank you very much @Larnu and Zohar_Peled! This works great!

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)